# NSFetchedResultsController - Add a section with no rows

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

NSFetchedResultsController Calendar Style App - Any idea how can I add a section with 0 rows like the Calendar app does when you don't have any appointments / events on the current day? 
I  really don't want to give up using a NSFetchedResultsController because it is fast and optimized but I'm out of ideas.

Data model suggestions are welcome too.

Comment: This is really a table view or collection view thing, rather than the fetched results controller. Your data source methods tell the view where there is (and isn't) data, this is where you would implement the behavior you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The data model solution is obvious: create a `Day` entity, populate it with sufficient dates (perhaps creating them ad hoc) and assign it to the events (Day->Event one-to-many). The events should still have their own start date etc. attributes of type `NSDate` - use the Day entity just for the section headers.

I would not advise to go down that route. Instead, you could tell your `datasource` to display the appropriate number of sections to represent the days and populate the section headers by calculating the date based on the `indexPath` and a starting date (for `indexPath.row == 0`).

You populate the rows by using the fetched results controllers `fetchedObjects` property. You will still get most of the optimizations you are after:

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"startDate > %@ && startDate < %@", sectionStartDate, sectionEndDate]];
NSArray *events = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects
    filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
Event *eventForRow = events[indexPath.row];
```

The section dates would be the appropriate dates at the beginning and end of the day.